# using WP shorcode to read an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to write a WP shortcode to read a price list which is organized as a 2 dimensional array. The shortage has 2 attributes - column and line - and should return the number at the column/line position in the price list array

With the draft code below, the shortcode returns seemingly random values from the array...

However when I plug actual integers instead of $atts['column'] and $atts['line'], all works and the shortocde returns the correct value from the array. Any idea ?

```html
// Add Shortcode
function price_shortcode( $atts ) {

 // Attributes
 $atts = shortcode_atts(
  array(
   'column' => '',
   'line' => '',
  ),
  $atts,
  'price'
 );

 // Return content of price list at specified location
 ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
 
 $PriceListArray = array();
 if (($handle = fopen("wp-content/themes/twentythirteen-child/pa/PriceList.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
         $PriceListArray[] = $data;
     }
     fclose($handle);
 }
 
 ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", false);
 
 
 return $PriceListArray[$atts['column']][$atts['line']];
 
 

}
add_shortcode( 'price', 'price_shortcode' );
```

Answer (score 0):

OOPs   I found the error...
When reading the array in :
return $PriceListArray[$atts['column']][$atts['line']];

the order of attributes should line then column, and not the opposite..

I would delete the question, but can not figure out if this is possible....